# How to create a link to a different part of a sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

Is there an excel feature that enables you to create a link to a different part of a sheet so you don't have to scroll down ... wherever, to get there ?

I have about 2000 tables in one sheet, and some "table of contents" listing all the tables. I'd like to create a link from the table of contents to the appropriate table (it's all within the same sheet).

Is something like that possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel 2007
Select the Insert Menu
Click Hyperlink
Choose "Place in this document"
Select a sheet and a cell.